# Getting p3016 error, when running npx prisma migrate dev --name init

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, prisma

I'm working on a Vite React project; I set up `prisma` to work with `ElephantSQL`, however I get this error when running the following command:
`npx prisma migrate dev --name init`

[image: Screenshot of P3016 error]

What does the error mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you found your way around ?